# WD MyCloud Setup Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm having problems mounting my WD Mycloud - here is what I've entered so far... What am I supposed to do next?

Current Version WDMyCloud v04.05.00-315
Linux Ubuntu 17.04

```
$ sudo mount -o rw,soft,intr,nfsvers=3 192.168.0.11:/nfs* /home/ashleyd72788/Desktop/"Media Server"
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.11:/nfs*
```

Answer (score 2):

In Nautilus, type <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to show the pathbar.

In the pathbar, type:

```
ssh://192.168.0.11
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Enter your WD login id and password to connect.

This will mount the network drive.

Comment: Awesome - I was able to access the folders. I am ultimately trying to set up my plex media server to pull from mycloud. Do you know if I can have my files automatically move to the cloud? I tried moving my media server folder to the nfs folder but it said there wasn't enough space (the cloud has 3tb avail)

Comment: `sshfs` is an alternative to `nfs` and uses the `ssh` protocol. If you want to mount the remote the network drive to a local mount using `sshfs`, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS. This may allow the plex server to read and write to the network drive.

Comment: If this worked for you, accept this answer, and post a separate question do help with automatically backing up / copying your files to WD.